# Group aggregation using spring data mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I tried to write a group aggregation query using the year value from a date object as a key, but for some reason I'm getting this exception.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property year(invoiceDate)
```

Here is the mongo query which I'm trying to replicate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
     $match:
     {
       "status": "Active"
     }
   },
   {
     $group:
     {
      "_id":{$year:"$invoiceDate"}
     }
  },
  {
    $sort:
    {
      "_id" : -1
    }
  }
])
```

And this is my Java implementation:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    match(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria())),
    Aggregation.group("year(invoiceDate)")
).withOptions(newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build());
```

I also didn't find a way how I can apply the sorting on the results from the grouping.

Comment: `Aggregation.sort()` - Why would it be called anything else?

Comment: I thought that you need to supply a reference in the sort method, but you are probably right. Any thoughts why the SpEL expression fails?

Comment: The `Aggregation.sort()` didn't work, I got `You have to provide at least one property to sort by!`

Comment: Sorry, it was just a quick comment whilst I was walking away for a while and intended more as a "prompt" to pick up the method and discover the options. Added the actual pipeline translations below.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically looking for `extractYear()` which maps to the [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) operator with MongoDB:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria())),
    Aggregation.project().and("invoiceDate").extractYear().as("_id"),
    Aggregation.group("_id"),
    Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id)
)
```

This generally needs to go into a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) in order to make the helpers happy.

If you really want the expression within the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) then you can add a custom operation expression:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
  Aggregation.match(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria())),
  new AggregationOperation() {
    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
      return new Document("$group",
        new Document("_id", new Document("$year","$invoiceDate") )
      );
    }
  },
  Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id)
)
```