# how to convert a date into timestamp in spring mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-mongo

I want to know how to convert these mongo cell query into spring mongo query

```
{$addFields:{"creationTime":{$toLong:"$creationTime"}}}
```

or

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$id","timestamp" : { "$push" : {$toLong:"$creationTime" }} } }
```

Comment: i found one way using below convrtor and then use projection var c=ConvertOperators.ConvertOperatorFactory("creationTime").convertToLong()
        var projectionOperation= Aggregation.project().and(c).`as`("creationTime")

Comment: `spring-mongodb` does not not support such expressions "directly" within a `$group`. You either do a separate `project()` first as you discovered, or construct a custom aggregation stage directly without "helpers". One such [example of the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50409636/2313887)